# Migrating from Boto2 to Boto3 while using python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

I am currently using boto2 to upload some files into an s3 bucket where the objects are sorted based on keys(which are generated) with the objects I am uploading. I am now required to migrate this script from boto2 to boto3 but the docs are a bit confusing.
Can someone please help with the code changes needed or the differences I need to be aware of? as I'm trying to use boto3 with python 2.7.(not possible to upgrade to python 3 at this time)

Parts of the script that uses boto2 needing to be migrated is below:

```
            if not boto.config.has_section('Credentials'):
            boto.config.add_section('Credentials')
            boto.config.set('Credentials', 'aws_access_key_id', '%aws_access_key_id%')
            boto.config.set('Credentials', 'aws_secret_access_key', '%aws_secret_access_key%')

        # Connect to S3
        self.s3conn = boto.connect_s3()
        self.bucket = self.s3conn.get_bucket('%aws_bucket%')
        self.prefix = "%aws_prefix%"
        self.manifest_prefix = "%aws_manifest%"
        self.domain = "%aws_domain%"

        self.s3_keys = []
        self.uploadTrack = {"i": 0, "total": 0}
        self.myprint("Generating list of files in bucket")
        timer = datetime.now()
        for key in self.bucket.list(prefix=self.prefix + remoteStorePath + "/"):
            # self.myprint(key.name.rstrip().split('/')[-1])
            self.s3_keys.append(key.name.rstrip().split('/')[-2] + key.name.rstrip().split('/')[-1])

        self.myprint(str(len(self.s3_keys)) + " files in s3 bucket took " + str(datetime.now() - timer))
```

different class further down in the script :

```
def upload_file(self, details, ttl='259200'):
    startTime = datetime.now()
    initialHash = details[:2]
    if initialHash == "zz":
        initialHash = "ad"
    local_file = os.path.join(overrideStorePath, "files", initialHash, details[2:])

    k = boto.s3.key.Key(self.bucket)

    k.key = self.prefix + remoteStorePath + '/' + details[:2] + '/' + details[2:]

    k.set_metadata('Cache-Control', 'max-age=' + ttl)
    k.set_contents_from_filename(local_file)
    i = self.uploadTrack["i"] + 1
    self.uploadTrack["i"] += 1
    total = self.uploadTrack["total"]
    p = int(100 * i / total)
    self.myprint("Uploaded '{}' : {} of {} :  {}% in {} : {} kb".format(k.name, str(i), str(total), str(p), str(datetime.now() - startTime), str(os.path.getsize(local_file) / 1024)))
    return True
```

There are more files being uploaded in a similar fashion to this second snippet of the script,
With this part I cant seem to figure out an equivalent to " `k = boto.s3.key.Key(self.bucket)`" in boto3.

Comment: Looking at the docs for boto3, you may be wasting your time.  https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.16.56/guide/migrationpy3.html

Comment: @MarkRansom according to the boto3 docs : 

"boto3 and botocore released after the deprecation date will no longer work with Python 2.7"

 boto3 Deprecation date Python 2.7 - July 15, 2021

"If you're using an existing installation of boto3 on Python 2, you can keep using it even after the deprecation date. That version of boto3, however, will not receive further feature or security updates"

Comment: @Dan_96 yeah, you can continue to use older versions, but python 2.x itself has been EOL for coming up on 2 years.

Comment: If you want to use AWS with no possibility of security updates, you're braver than I am.  You'll also find yourself increasingly isolated as your setup diverges with the rest of the world.

Comment: As others pointed out, you should move to p3. You have good excuse now. This problem will only be getting worse over time, so its better to address it now.

Comment: The `k = key.Key` thing seems to be similar to the boto3 'resource' method, as opposed to the 'client' method. Frankly, you should replace all that `k` stuff with a simple `s3_client.upload_file()` call, rather than attempting to map every line to boto3 individually.

Comment: I am using this in TeamCity and there are 100+ other scripts at work that uses python 2.7 which is why I'm stuck with this for the time being. I understand the deprecation issues and security concerns but we decided this is the best way to continue until we upgrade to python3 the end of this year.